# Higher level project management (portfolio management) software?

Tags: project-management, project-planning

Probably not the best wording for that question but...

I understand there are things like MS Project to manage tasks within a project, however I'm looking for something one level higher.  I need to be able to manage projects and available resources themselves, rather than just tasks within a project.

For instance

```
ProjectA 1/1/2009-1/14/2009  ResourceA, ResourceB, ResourceC
ProjectB 1/5/2009-1/12/2009 ResourceD, ResourceE
ProjectC 1/15/2009-2/20/2009 ResourceB, ResourceC
```

So basically I would be able to add a new project, see what resources are available, estimate when we can start and complete it all by looking at the software.  (Then I could show management they're waiting until 2099 if they don't hire some more people. ;) )

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do exactly that with MS projects, just think about your company as a big project, and each projects as tasks on which ressources are assigned. Still I wouldn't recommend MS project because it doesn't scale well, but if you only want to make a gantt chart in order to support your point, it will do a good job.

In my experience, people managing multiple projects use custom excel sheet and it usually do the job well. Exemple: Timeline in the first columns, one column per ressource per projects, drop down for actual ressource.

Comment: This is basically what I ended up doing.  It's not quite ideal, but at least now I know I'm only booked through the end of August!

Answer (score 2):

http://daptiv.com/

A client uses it, but I can't comment on how much of a success it has been for them.

Another (better?) term for this is probably "Portfolio Management".

Comment: daptive looks good, but it also looks expensive...

Answer (score 0):

We use something called Clarity, and another product called OpenWorkbench where I work.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Project Server has a portfolio management facility. I haven't used it, but I understand it works.